# How can I rename the column in BigQuery table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rename

I have the following structure:

```
|       Field name                   |    Type    |    Mode    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
event_id                             |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
payload                              |   RECORD   |  NULLABLE  |
  |-version                          |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
  |-plan                             |   RECORD   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-legs                         |   RECORD   |  REPEATED  |
          |-id                       |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
          |-shipmentLinks            |   RECORD   |  REPEATED  |
              |-id                   |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
              |-source               |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
```

And I want to rename the column id to shipmentLinkId in a new table by running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table_renamed`
AS
SELECT 
  event_id, 
  payload.version,
  payload.plan.legs.id,
  payload.plan.legs.shipmentLinks.id AS shipmentLinkId,
  payload.plan.legs.shipmentLinks.source
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
```

But I can not run the query successfully. The error I get:

> Cannot access field id on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<id STRING,
> shipmentLinks STRUCT<id STRING, source STRING>>> at

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you still face issue after removing extra comma ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. the real reason is because legs is a repeated column. I'll add the actual error to the question

Comment: Ok, Yes Plz. That will help us to solve it together :)

Comment: I updated the answer, Can you let me know, if you still face the issue ?

Comment: Do you want to change the schema of original table with another field name ? or trying to flatten the nested and repeated table structure ?

Comment: I want to want to change the schema of original table with another field name @Jaytiger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to change the schema of original table with another field name.

Below will return the table with field name `shipmentLinkId` instead of `id`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table_renamed` AS
SELECT event_id,
       (SELECT AS STRUCT payload.version,
         ARRAY(
           SELECT AS STRUCT
                  id,
                  ARRAY( -- change *id* to *shipmentLinkId*
                    SELECT AS STRUCT id AS shipmentLinkId, source FROM legs.shipmentLinks
                  ) shipmentLinks
             FROM t.payload.plan.legs
         ) AS plan
       ) AS payload
  FROM `project.dataset.table_name` t;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- you can see `id` is changed to `shipmentLinkId`

Comment: If you want to flatten the table, you can try Tushar's answer with fixing `payload.plan.legs.id` to `leg.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current error tells that;

> payload.plan.legs.shipmentLinks column is an array

So, you need to flatten it using [UNNEST function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) before you access fields in it to create a new table.

The following query shall solve your issue :

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table_renamed`
AS
SELECT 
  event_id, 
  payload.version,
  payload.plan.legs.id,
  shipmentLink.id AS shipmentLinkId,
  shipmentLink.source
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`,
UNNEST(payload.plan.legs) AS leg,
UNNEST(leg.shipmentLinks) AS shipmentLink;
```